# R: Convert a data.frame into a list with tags from data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df0 <- data.frame(N1    = c("A","B")
                , N2    =c("C","C")
                , value =c(10,10)
                )
> df0
  N1 N2 value
1  A  C    10
2  B  C    10
```

I would like to convert into a list with the following structure:

```
list0 <- list( A= list( C= 10 )
             , B= list( C= 10 ) 
             )
> list0
$A
$A$C
[1] 10

$B
$B$C
[1] 10

> str(list0)
List of 2
 $ A:List of 1
  ..$ C: num 10
 $ B:List of 1
  ..$ C: num 10
```

Any idea? My problem is to get tags (names) instead of indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` function:

```
list0 <- setNames(apply(df0, 1, function(row) {
                 a <- list()
                 a[[row[2]]] <- as.numeric(row[3]) 
                 return (a) 
              }), df0$N1)
list0
$A
$A$C
[1] 10


$B
$B$C
[1] 10


str(list0)
List of 2
 $ A:List of 1
  ..$ C: num 10
 $ B:List of 1
  ..$ C: num 10
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar with lapply but didn't succeed.

Comment: This solution works with `apply` function instead of `lapply`.

Comment: I meant I tried it before I saw your solution. Thanks again. With your solution as template it is possible to build every kind of complex list from a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
split(setNames(as.list(df0$value),df0$N2),df0$N1)
```

Comment: Identical solution in a different style: load `magrittr` or `dplyr` and then `as.list(df0$value) %>% setNames(df0$N2) %>% split(df0$N1)`

Comment: Thanks for this solution.